# Flutter, how to return different widget based on future value?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, dart-async

I would like to base on a future bool value, to set different icons pass back to a data card inside a list, I tried .then or FutureBuilder, but still not successful.

Scaffold:

```
child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: fullList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return dataCard(context, fullList, index);
                    }),
```

dataCard:

```
Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 8,
                    child: Text(dl[i].Name,
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[400], fontSize: 16)),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: setFavouriteIcon(dl[i].ID),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

setFavouriteIcon:

```
Widget setFavouriteIcon(_id) {
  final marked = markedFavourites(_id).then((value) {  //markedFavourites returns Future<bool>
    if (value == true) {
      return Icon(
        size: 24,
        Icons.favorite,
        color: Colors.red,
      );
    } else {
      return Icon(
        size: 24,
        Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
        color: Colors.red,
      );
    }
  });
  return Text('');  //Without this line, Error: A non-null value must be returned
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include other state as well on FutureBuilder

```dart
Widget setFavouriteIcon(_id) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: markedFavourites(_id),// you shouldn't call method directly here on statefulWidget case
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      
      final value = snapshot.hasData && (snapshot.data as bool? ?? false);
      if (value == true) {
        return Icon(
          size: 24,
          Icons.favorite,
          color: Colors.red,
        );
      } else {
        return Icon(
          size: 24,
          Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
          color: Colors.red,
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yeasin.  I have wrapped the 2 Icons within GestureDectector to add/remove favourite, it works on database level,  would you please teach me how to refresh the particular card when icon being pressed?

Comment: try to use the `_id` on filtering. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73441490/10157127) or better find `how to select select specific item on listView`

Answer (score 0):

you should use FutureBuilder

```
class FavoriteWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const FavoriteWidget({super.key});


// some future value
  Future<bool> markedFavorites() async {
//do smth 
    return true;
// or return false 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: markedFavorites(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data!) {
              return const Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
                color: Colors.red,
              );
            }
            return const Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```